# Selenium Webdriver using Proxy IP

Tags: selenium-webdriver, proxy, web-scraping, http-proxy

I was using selenium webdriver to scrap data from a website.due to heavy traffic from My IP, now i am not able to access website (may be my ip is blocked for the website).

Is there any way to **setup the Proxy IP**, so that it would be treated as a new IP every-time i run the webdriver..?

Comment: true it'll be treated as the new IP depending on the proxy IP pool you gonna use.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin  but my concern is how to setup the Proxy ip with webdriver.

Comment: I know it. So do you use Selenium with python? Could you expose what you've already done?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin i am using it with java.
as well as just creating a FF driver instance using following code
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://whatsmyip.net/");

Comment: have you looked [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set proxy IP with selenium webdriver as per following way :

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addAdditionalPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
profile.addAdditionalPreference("network.proxy.http_port", "8080");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

You should change your desired IP address and port in above code.

For more detail , Please have a look at : [Selenium Webdriver with proxy](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)

Comment: I have used above code & its working.
Do you have any website where we can get the  proxy IPs which will work 100% ,as i visited several sites (i.e http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/search-1291967#listable)they provide the ip & ports but by using them we are getting 50% success rate.

Comment: I will look for same and will update you once get site.

Answer (score 1):

Since you scrape a lot you'll probably need a reliable *proxy provider*. So most of them provide their own api for auth and using their proxy pool.
I've got this piece of code (java) from [Luminati.io](http://luminati.io/)

```
package example;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.*;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("zproxy.luminati.io", 22225);
        String res = Executor.newInstance()
            .auth(proxy, "lum-customer-CUSTOMER-zone-YOURZONE", "YOURPASS")
            .execute(Request.Get("http://www.telize.com/geoip").viaProxy(proxy))
            .returnContent().asString();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

There are more complex example codes there.

### Non-professional scrape

If you just want to plug in any deliberate proxy IP to test, you might use this:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
host='149.215.113.110' 
port='9150'
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http", host);
profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http_port", int(port));
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```